# docker node ls is showing only master node in Azure

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm, azure-container-service

I have created container environment in Azure. However, while running `docker node ls`, it is only showing LEADER node. but not showing agent node here.
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command to create a swarm, the Docker Engine starts running in swarm mode.

Run `docker swarm init` to create a single-node swarm on the current node. The Engine sets up the swarm as follows:

- switches the current node into swarm mode.
- creates a swarm named `default`.
- designates the current node as a leader manager node for the swarm.
- names the node with the machine hostname.
- configures the manager to listen on an active network interface on port 2377.
- sets the current node to `Active` availability, meaning it can receive tasks from the scheduler.
- starts an internal distributed data store for Engines participating in the swarm to maintain a consistent view of the swarm and all services running on it.
- by default, generates a self-signed root CA for the swarm.
- by default, generates tokens for worker and manager nodes to join the swarm.
  creates an overlay network named `ingress` for publishing service ports external to the swarm.
- creates an overlay default IP addresses and subnet mask for your networks
  The output for `docker swarm init` provides the connection command to use when you join new worker nodes to the swarm:

[Illustration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOajn.png)

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-mode/#create-a-swarm

For more information see [Join a worker node](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/join-nodes/#join-as-a-worker-node)

Once a worker node has joined the swarm docker `docker node ls` should give you the list of nodes joined to the swarm. [[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/)]